# Switch to connect/disconnect 7 lanes (maybe 7pdt?? switch)

Tags: switches

I'm looking to take a 6s Lipo Battery balance lead  (7 pins), and run them to one of two sockets.  One with a charge meter, and the other with a charger.

I want a switch that will toggle between the two sockets.

I've searched for various switches or ways of doing this, but cannot find anything (short of having 4 dpdt)

Is there any way I can achieve this with a single switch?

Comment: Close but missing one position: https://tinyurl.com/szy4x2p - Else this one for panel mount but be quick to buy (only 2 left at this moment): https://tinyurl.com/r68l934

Comment: https://eu.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/_/N-5g2h?keyword=8PDT    Just use an 8PDT and leave one pole unused.

Comment: Thank you both.  
These will do the trick I think.

Comment: QUestion - is there any harm in leaving both connected in parallel?

Comment: @PhilG - Actually, no, not while in use, but I do want a disconnect so the monitor doesn't slowly drain the batteries, as this will be a permanent connection.  (6s battery in a box with a charge meter.  Used to power a ts100 soldering iron as a portable solution.

Comment: It's just that the current rating for (reasonably priced) multipole switches is limited. They'll be fine for disconnection the monitor, but probably not a good choice for the charger.Presumably the changer has the 5 inter-cell taps for charge balancing, but only the end connections will be seeing the full charging current.